# QTextEdit shift-tab wrong behaviour

Tags: qt, qtextedit, qplaintextedit

shift+tab behaves as tab in QTextEdit/QPlainTextEdit.

Looks like a common problem with no good solution.

Is there any "classical" way to enable this functionality when tab increases indentation level and shift-tab decreases it?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of an old question, but I got this figured out.
You just need to reimplement QPlainTextEdit (or QTextEdit) with your own class that inherits from it, and override the keyPressEvent.

By default a tab inserts a tabstop, but the below code catches a `Qt.Key_Backtab` event, which as near as I can tell is the event that occurs when you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

I tried and failed to catch `Qt.Key_Tab` and a `Qt.Key_Shift` or `Qt.Key_Tab` and a Shift modifier, so this must be the way to do it.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class TabPlainTextEdit(QtGui.QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        QtGui.QTextEdit.__init__(self, parent)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Backtab:
            cur = self.textCursor()
            # Copy the current selection
            pos = cur.position() # Where a selection ends
            anchor = cur.anchor() # Where a selection starts (can be the same as above)

            # Can put QtGui.QTextCursor.MoveAnchor as the 2nd arg, but this is the default
            cur.setPosition(pos) 

            # Move the position back one, selection the character prior to the original position
            cur.setPosition(pos-1,QtGui.QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)

            if str(cur.selectedText()) == "\t":
                # The prior character is a tab, so delete the selection
                cur.removeSelectedText()
                # Reposition the cursor with the one character offset
                cur.setPosition(anchor-1)
                cur.setPosition(pos-1,QtGui.QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
            else:
                # Try all of the above, looking before the anchor (This helps if the achor is before a tab)
                cur.setPosition(anchor) 
                cur.setPosition(anchor-1,QtGui.QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
                if str(cur.selectedText()) == "\t":
                    cur.removeSelectedText()
                    cur.setPosition(anchor-1)
                    cur.setPosition(pos-1,QtGui.QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
                else:

                    # Its not a tab, so reset the selection to what it was
                    cur.setPosition(anchor)
                    cur.setPosition(pos,QtGui.QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
        else:
            return QtGui.QTextEdit.keyPressEvent(self, event)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TabPlainTextEdit(None)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm still refining this, but the [rest of the code is on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/LegoStormtroopr/6146161).